# Change global variable in a module from a function defined in another module

Tags: python, global

I have a module with a main function that runs a loop while a flag is true.
In the loop, there is a call to a function defined in another module that check a conditions and should stop the main loop if it's True.

The code is:

**main.py**

```
import other

isRunning = True
def shutdown():
    global isRunning
    isRunning = False

def main():
    while isRunning:
        # some logic here
        other.check()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**other.py**

```
import main

def check():
    someCondition = #some logic to check the condition
    if someCondition:
        main.shutdown()
```

The code is run launching the `main.py` file.

The issue is that when `other.check()` is called in the loop, the `main.shutdown()` function is called but the main loop keeps running. In the main loop the `isRunning` variable is always `True`, but I was expecting it to become `False` after being set in the `main.shutdown()` function.
Why is this happening? What am I missing?

I could refactor the code to mange the exit from the loop in a smarter way, but I am interested to know if there is a solution keeping this kind of code structure.

Comment: You probably need a `global isRunning` statement in main().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `main.py` file being loaded twice. It first gets loaded as `__main__` when you run it as a script. It also gets imported by `other.py` as its regular name `main`.

The two copies are completely separate from each other, and have separate global variables! When `other.check` calls `main.shutdown` to modify the `isRunning` global variable, it only changes the `main.isRunning` version, not `__main__.isRunning`. The main function is checking `__main__.isRunning` which doesn't ever get changed.

There are several ways you can fix this. The best is probably to get rid of your circular import in some way. While circular importing *can* work OK in Python, it's often a symptom of bad design. It's a very bad idea to use it with any module that may be run as a script.

Comment: I know that this design is bad, I was just doing some quick tests to check some ideas and I stepped in this issue. I did not know what you described, it will be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import other


def main():
    while other.run():
        # some logic here
        other.check()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

other.py

```
import main

isRunning = True
def run():
    return isRunning

def check():
    global isRunning
    someCondition = #some logic to check the condition
    if someCondition:
        isRunning = False
```

If I was you I would use objects and classes..., global methods and variables are not "debug and maintenance friendly"